# Error: Cannot find module '/node_modules\progressbar/package.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, progress-bar, browserify

I am using Browserify and progressbar.js to `var ProgressBar = require('node_modules/progressbar');` but the progress bar is not being generating I am getting the following error `Error: Cannot find module '/node_modules\progressbar/package.json'`

```
'use strict';

    window.onload = function onLoad() {

        var ProgressBar = require('progressbar');

        var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#progress', {
            color: 'red',
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'easeInOut'
        });
        circle.animate(1);
    }
```

In the Browserify bundle file `.call(this,"/node_modules\\progressbar")}`

How I installed progressbar.js

```
npm install --save progressbar
```

Installed Browserify

```
npm install -g browserify
```

To check that my Browserify was installed properly I

```
npm ramda
```

and that bundles correctly, so the problem is with progressbar.js?

[npm progressbar.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progressbar)

[progressbar.js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/)

Comment: You shouldn't need to include `node_modules` in the path, it is implicit: `var ProgressBar = require('progressbar');`

Comment: yes I also tried require('progressbar'); and got the say error. I was reaading on a github forum that one solution was to add ```node_modules/``` relative path?

Comment: How did you install it? Did you use `npm install progressbar`? The error is saying that it can't find the `package.json` file, so you may want to open up `node_modules/progressbar` and ensure that the file exists, permissions are ok and that there wasn't a problem installing

Comment: @RobM. I have updated the question with how I installed progressbar.js and yes the progressbar.js file is in the right location ```node_modules/progressbar/package.json```  I wonder does the error have something to do with the \ in the path?

Comment: Are you on a windows machine? That *could* be a correct path on windows but it won't be on linux or mac. Seems more likely that your issue is with your browserify setup than the code you posted.

Comment: Correct I'm on a Windows box. Hmm I installed Browserify with ```npm install -g browserify``` Is it worth doing a reinstall or is there a way I can check if Browserify is installed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's helpful to anyone stumbling across this issue/thread....instead of:

```
npm install progressbar
```

...and...

```
var ProgressBar = require('progressbar');
```

I went with:

```
npm install progressbar.js
```

...and...

```
var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js');
```

These appear to be two different projects coincidentally and progressbarjs (progressbar.js: https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) was that I kept running across on the web when searching for JS progress bars.  The other (progressbar) doesn't appear to behave well with Browserify for whatever reason.  Note that I'm confident my Browserify is behaving as it should because it's handling numerous other packages for my current project without any issues whatsoever.

Gotta love the world of javascript....